# upload and modify a file for each user and then download it using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am working on a laravel project in which the user uploads a file that server modifies, the user then can download it (no username and password authentication). Uploading and modifying is done in a controller and downloading is done in a different controller. My question is how to return the file that this user uploaded? how can i mark the file that belongs to him and not other file? should i take into account tokens?

This is what i want to be done in download controller:

```
 protected function getDownload(Request $request){

    $file = "path to the file that belongs to this user";
    return Response::download($file);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the file in the database. Create a files table and create the following fields in it:

```
id| original_name| modified_name| mime| user_id/user_hash ...
```

You need to create such fields to know that the file that was uploaded corresponds to the one modified. For example, you modify the file name, so I put the field in its original name and modified.

To attach a file to an unregistered user, that is, who has no id in the database, you can generate a hash and write in the **user_hash** field. Also, put this hash in a cookie to the user so that next time you know what he downloaded the file. If this user is in the database just put it id in **user_id**